# CentOS 6 server is in hang state. Error on console: waiting for required block device discovery

Tags: centos, centos6

CentOS 6 server is in the hang state and showing following errors on the console:

**waiting for required block device discovery

waiting for 4 sda-like device(s)...**

Does anyone knows the reason behind this error?

server specification:
OS: CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final)
Hard Ware: HP  ProLiant DL180 G6

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a kernel panic to me.

Did the server boot corectly after your reset?

Suggestions

Check the filesystems just to make sure everything is fine

Are you using CentOS 6.0 or CentOS 6.x (where x is the current release number - like 6.5).
In case you're stuck at CentOS 6.0 I strongly suggest to upgrade to the recent 6.5 as this includes many bug and security fixes! Besides that it's the only version receiving continous support by the CentOS team.

I also remember that we've had a similar issue with a customer machine a while ago. When we upgraded the machine from CentOS 6.2 to a more recent version the issue was resolved. I think this was related to a kernel module that got fixed in 6.4.